# Batch get file contents

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that is suppose to search for a file with a specific extension in the directory, and then get that file's extensions. It succesfully finds the file but for some reason it's not able to read it. What could the issue be?

Here is my code:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion



::Find the file
for /r %%i in (*.extension) do set file=%%~nxi

::Get that file's contents (not working)
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%file%) do set Build=%%x




::returns nothing.
echo %Build%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script sets variable "file" to only the filename (no path).  Then you try to open the filename (no path).  On my system, I received a "The system cannot find the file..." error.

This leads me to believe that in your script, the find file line uses the bat file's current path, but the read file does not.  My guess it is because of the "*" in the find line.

I fixed by simply changing your find file line to:

```
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do set file=%%i
```

Now the variable "file" will be the complete path+filename and the batch file found my file and read the text.